# Include the previous mail as a clause in the new mail

Tags: job-offer, email

I have to decline the new salary offer from the current company they have provided upon my notice of resignation w.e.f 1/1/1111(Say). I am replying for the mail after 5 days. By the time, I need to include a legal clause to ensure that my notice period will be valid from 1/1/1111 (not from the current date) as per the notice of resignation.

So my question is how to send a mail including a legal clause under the mail content. Is there any format for that?

Comment: Welcome to [workplace.se] log_in! There doesn't seem to be a question you are asking. Could you please make an [edit] to explain the problem more clearly, and include a question that you are looking to have answered? It may help to take a look at our [help/on-topic] to make sure your question will get good answers. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edited the question. Sorry if the question again doesn't sound well.

Comment: Legal questions are not on topic here (when they require input by a lawyer), which is what it sounds like your question is asking for. My understanding is that you resigned via an e-mail. Your company offered you a higher salary not to quit. You want to turn down the increased salary and make sure your previous resignation is kept. Right? I don't understand why you need a *"legal clause"* to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is how to send a mail including a legal clause under
>   the mail content. Is there any format for that?

I think you are hinting at the correct way to proceed here.

In your mail which rejects their counter-offer, include your original resignation notice mail, including the original resignation date.

You should probably also re-state your end date. Something along the lines of

"Since my resignation was originally offered on 1/1/1111, my last work date will be 2/1/1111" (or whatever end date your contract requires).

*I am not a lawyer. For legal correctness, you must read your contract and possibly consult an attorney.*